# Reemplazar for por programación funcional

Tags: javascript, programación-funcional

estoy haciendo base en la programación funcional, haciendo muchos ejemplos tengo este, el cual deseo calcular ciertos datos para ingresarlos a una gráfica, el punto seria, como elimino el for, esto de los reduce y filtrados me tiene confusa, creo que podría usar un reduce y sacar la multiplicación de `p` pero no se exactamente como iterar.. me tocaría hacer un array con los números que deseo multiplicar?

```js
let p = 5;
let a = 50;
let empty = [];

for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
  let kk = i * a;
  let val = Number((kk * p).toFixed());
  empty.push({label:kk, value:val});
}

console.log(empty);
```

gracias a los que puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no estoy muy relacionado con la programación funcional, pero por lo que veo la función que te ayudaría sería `map()` que trabaja sobre arrays, así que deberías crear un array con los números que quieras usar y aplicar lo demás con map. Aquí te dejo el ejemplo de como lo implementé:

```
a = [...Array(10).keys()].map(n => (n+1)*50).map(n => n={label:n,value:n*5})
```

Primero creo el array con números del 0 al 9, luego hago `(n+1)*50` para cada número(el +1 es porque inicia en 0), y de nuevo realizo otro mapeo donde acomodo con label y value, haciendo la última multiplicación y dá como resultado:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {label: 50, value: 250}
    1: {label: 100, value: 500}
    2: {label: 150, value: 750}
    3: {label: 200, value: 1000}
    4: {label: 250, value: 1250}
    5: {label: 300, value: 1500}
    6: {label: 350, value: 1750}
    7: {label: 400, value: 2000}
    8: {label: 450, value: 2250}
    9: {label: 500, value: 2500}
length: 10
```

Igual lo puedes realizar todo con un solo map, o alguna otra mejor forma, pero es lo que se me ocurrió, espero te sirva de algo, saludos.

Comment: sip definitivamente si, que facil, jjjjj gracias Luis, muy amable.